# How to show confirm message on condition on asp button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, confirm

I have a checkbox cbDue that is by default checked but can be unchecked on certain conditions. When I click the Submit button it should check if the cbDue is checked or not. If cbdue is checked, then it should show confirm message "This is for current month?". if user clicks Yes then the code in the Onclick event of the submit button will run. If user clicks No to the message then the code will not run.

So I need to show the confirm message box On Condition, not always.

Edit: My Checkbox

Submit button:
 
JavaScript:
function Confirm() {

```
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Submit for current month?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
```

Code behind for btnSubmit (partly)
If cbDue.Checked = True Then
            If confirmValue = "No" Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
This works some what but shows the message every time I click the submit button.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: show effort and code in a [mcve]

Comment: So get the cbDue checkbox element in JavaScript and check if it's checked or not, and if it is then show your confirm.

Comment: I have tried the following but not working. I am new to javascript so if any one can help me in right direction.                               function confirmation() {
            var DueChecked = ('<%=cbDue.ClientID%>').checked;
            if (Duechecked) {
                confirm('are you sure you want to delete ?')                  
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

The code that is working for me - 
function confirmation() {
         var DueChecked = document.getElementById('MainContent_cbDue').checked;

```
     if (DueChecked == true) {
         if ( confirm('Submit for current month?') == true) {

             return true;
         }else{
             return false;
         } 

     } else {

         return true;
     }
 }

 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit For Review" CssClass="submitBtn" ValidationGroup="ReviewDue" OnClientClick="return confirmation();" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```